# Filter booked appointments by business working hour

Tags: python-3.x, django, scheduling

Business working hours(TimeField) are stored for everyday in UTC time.

BusinessHours table

```
business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
day = models.CharField(max_length=10)
opening_time = models.TimeField()
closing_time = models.TimeField()
```

Appointment table

```
appointment_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm trying to get particular day's appointments for the stored business hours range(between opening_time and closing_time). Here is the query

```
appointments = models.Appointments.objects.filter(service_start_time__week_day=3, service_start_time__gte=datetime.utcnow(), service_start_time__time__range=(day_obj.opening_time, day_obj.closing_time))
```

Sometimes the `opening_time` may be greater than the `closing_time`. Above query is not getting the records due to this reason.

For 03:00(opening) Indian standard Time to UTC is 22:30 and 20:00(closing) corresponding UTC is 14:30. In this case opening time seems greater than closing time. Query doesn't filter anything even though appointments available. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to convert your input from UTC to IST.

1. `pip install pytz` to install the pytz library that is handy when you do something like this
2. `now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))` this will give you current utc time
3. `now_asia = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))` this will now give you IST time for that same UTC datetime
4. `appointments = models.Appointments.objects.filter(service_start_time__week_day=3, service_start_time__gte=now_asia, service_start_time__time__range=(day_obj.opening_time, day_obj.closing_time))` <--your this query will defer as per your filter requirement so make changes accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, please note that appointment time also in UTC date time format, is it correct to query the datetime in IST? Also let me know `service_start_time__time__range=(day_obj.opening_time, day_obj.closing_time))` is that should be in UTC/IST